# XML to c# string array

Tags: xml

I have a xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<case>
   <e>
      <Time>05-08-2018 11:46:19</Time>
      <Number null="true"/>
      <code1 null="true"/>
      <code2>27341</code2>
      <code3>27341</code3>
   </e>
   <e>
      <Time>05-07-2018 12:11:19</Time>
      <Number>WC1110</Number>
      <code1>50121</code1>
      <code2>54091</code2>
      <code3>14880</code3>
   </e>
</case>
```

I want to get both the tag name and the value into a string[] result, such that

```
result[0] = "Time,05-08-2018 11:46:19";
result[1] = "Number,";
result[2] = "code1,";
result[3] = "code2,27341";
result[4] = "code3,27341";

result[5] = "Time,05-07-2018 12:11:19";
result[6] = "Number,WC1110";
result[7] = "code1,50121";
result[8] = "code2,54091";
result[9] = "code3,14880";
```

I have tried the following code, without specifying the tag name (dynamic), it only get the non null value but cannot get the tag name.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(finalResult);
var rows = from row in doc.Root.Elements("case") select row;
var result = rows.SelectMany(o => o.Elements())
            .OrderBy(o => o.Name.LocalName)
            .Select(o => (string)o).ToArray();
```

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of having '<Number null="true"/>' to indicate the tag has no value, just try the following way <Number></Number>

Comment: I know, but actually I cannot control the incoming tag format

Answer (score 0):

I Used the Paste Special -> Paste XML As Class method to generate the class and use the generated method to get the value